# How to stop auto editing the `myTimestamp` field of androidTest configuration xml file in Android Studio 3

Tags: android-studio, android-testing

I want to share androidTest configurations with team members.
So I added the xml file which is in `.idea/runConfgurations` directory to git.

The xml contents are:

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
<configuration default="false" name="xxx" type="AndroidTestRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Android Instrumented Tests">
    <module name="xxx" />
    <option name="TESTING_TYPE" value="0" />
    <option name="INSTRUMENTATION_RUNNER_CLASS" value="" />
    <option name="METHOD_NAME" value="" />
    <option name="CLASS_NAME" value="" />
    <option name="PACKAGE_NAME" value="" />
    <option name="EXTRA_OPTIONS" value="" />
    <option name="CLEAR_LOGCAT" value="false" />
    <option name="SHOW_LOGCAT_AUTOMATICALLY" value="false" />
    <option name="SKIP_NOOP_APK_INSTALLATIONS" value="true" />
    <option name="FORCE_STOP_RUNNING_APP" value="true" />
    <option name="TARGET_SELECTION_MODE" value="USB_DEVICE" />
    <option name="USE_LAST_SELECTED_DEVICE" value="false" />
    <option name="PREFERRED_AVD" value="" />
    <option name="SELECTED_CLOUD_MATRIX_CONFIGURATION_ID" value="-1" />
    <option name="SELECTED_CLOUD_MATRIX_PROJECT_ID" value="" />
    <option name="DEBUGGER_TYPE" value="Auto" />
    <Auto>
    <option name="USE_JAVA_AWARE_DEBUGGER" value="false" />
    <option name="SHOW_STATIC_VARS" value="true" />
    <option name="WORKING_DIR" value="" />
    <option name="TARGET_LOGGING_CHANNELS" value="lldb process:gdb-remote packets" />
    <option name="SHOW_OPTIMIZED_WARNING" value="true" />
    </Auto>
    <Hybrid>
    <option name="USE_JAVA_AWARE_DEBUGGER" value="false" />
    <option name="SHOW_STATIC_VARS" value="true" />
    <option name="WORKING_DIR" value="" />
    <option name="TARGET_LOGGING_CHANNELS" value="lldb process:gdb-remote packets" />
    <option name="SHOW_OPTIMIZED_WARNING" value="true" />
    </Hybrid>
    <Java />
    <Native>
    <option name="USE_JAVA_AWARE_DEBUGGER" value="false" />
    <option name="SHOW_STATIC_VARS" value="true" />
    <option name="WORKING_DIR" value="" />
    <option name="TARGET_LOGGING_CHANNELS" value="lldb process:gdb-remote packets" />
    <option name="SHOW_OPTIMIZED_WARNING" value="true" />
    </Native>
    <Profilers>
    <option name="ADVANCED_PROFILING_ENABLED" value="false" />
    </Profilers>
    <method>
    <option name="com.android.instantApps.provision.BeforeRunTask" enabled="true" clearCache="false" clearProvisionedDevices="false" myTimestamp="1520471250647" />
    <option name="Android.Gradle.BeforeRunTask" enabled="true" />
    </method>
</configuration>
</component>
```

But, Android Studio would change `myTimestamp` field at start-up.

After relaunched Android Studio:

```
myTimestamp="1520471982934"
```

That is not good for version control. 
How can I stop it?